# 'Followers' and efficiency

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures, twitter

I am designing an app that would involve users 'following' each other's activity, in the twitter sense, but I am not very experienced with database/query design/efficiency. Are there best practices for managing this, pitfalls to avoid, etc.? I gather this can create a very large load on the db if not done properly (or maybe even then?).

If it makes a difference it is likely that people will 'follow' only a relatively small number of people (but a person may have many followers). However this is not certain, and I wouldn't want to count on it.

Any advice gratefully received. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty simple and easy to do with full [normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  If you have a table of users, each with a unique ID, you would have a `TABLE_FOLLOWERS` table with the columns, `USERID` and `FOLLOWERID` which would describe all the followers for each user as a one to one to many relationship.

Even with millions of assosciations on a half decent database server this will perform well and fast as long as you are using a good database (IE, not MS-Access).

Comment: I know it's been long, I am wondering `FOLLOWERID`would store multiple values?

Answer (score 4):

The model is fairly simple. The problem is in the size of the **Subscription** table; if there are 1 million users, and each subscribes to 1000, then the **Subscription** table has 1 billion rows.

[image: follower_model.png]

Comment: @Damir .. could you explain the sense of "EnableSubscription" in your diagram? Is that a bool? How should this work either way, follow and follow back? And why the use of a bool? Can't one just use a pivot table and reference the userID both as User and Follower? Is that EnableSubcription used for maybe banning a user from following you?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how many users you expect to need to support; how many followers you expect users to have; and what sort of funding/development-effort you expect to have access to should your answers to the previous questions prove optimistic.

For a small scale project I would likely ignore the database, design the application as a simple object model with `User` objects that maintain a `List[followers]`. Keep it all in RAM for normal operation and use an ORM to persist to a database periodically (probably postgresql or mysql).

For a larger project I would not be using a relational database at all; but exactly what I would use would depend on the specific details of the project.

If you are only trying to spike the concept, go with the ORM approach; but, keep in mind it won't scale.

Comment: Would you mind pointing me in the direction of some introductory material on RAM object storage? What technologies are we talking about, in particular? Something like Redis?

Comment: For a spike I actually mean maintaining simple datastructures directly in RAM. Assuming 100,000 users, with an average of 100 followers, and a simple ~100-byte object per user, and 4-byte references you only require ~40MB for the follower graph and 10MB for the user DB. Even with indexing overhead of 3x that is easily something you can fit in RAM and persist without too much difficulty to a DB.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should read http://highscalability.com/ and it's articles on how this is managed by the big sites.